# Rails will_paginate and ajax append pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, will-paginate

I'm using the will_paginate gem with ajax to append the next page to the bottom of my index every time the user clicks "more" - the problem I'm noticing is that past the second page, clicking more just appends the second page again - what am i missing?

**index.html.erb**

```
<ul class="items" id="event-index">
<%= render 'events' %>
</ul>
<%= will_paginate @events, :previous_label => '', :next_label => 'More', :remote => true %>
```

**index.js.erb**

```
$('#event-index').append('<%= escape_javascript(render("events")) %>');

<% if @events.total_pages == @events.current_page %>
    $('.pagination').remove();
<% end %>
<% if @events.current_page %>
    $('.ajaxload').hide();
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your setup is that the link that shows the next page doesn't get updated.  It always shows the second page. The simplest solution I can think of is to always delete the pagination and rerender it.

```
$('#event-index').append('<%= escape_javascript(render("events")) %>');
$('.pagination').remove();

<% if @events.next_page %>
  $('#event-index').after('<%= will_paginate @events, :previous_label => '', :next_label => 'More', :remote => true %>');
<% end %>

<% if @events.current_page %>
  $('.ajaxload').hide();
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem with this is that the URL rendered is http://localhost:3000/events?_=1378058046263&page=3 which then kills the ajax request and makes it load the 3rd page as a full page load

Comment: I think the issue here is that the javascript function isn't being reloading thus the URL is returned that way

`$(function() {
  $(".pagination a").on("click", function(event) {
  $('.ajaxload').show();
    $.getScript(this.href);
    return false;
  });
});`

Comment: are you sure you added `remote: true` to the link in `index.js.erb`?  that should trigger an ajax request.